# How can I set my imageView to fill my UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode

I create my custom UICollectionViewCell (MyCell) for my UICollectionView in storyboard.
I add a UIIMageView as the child of my custom UICollectionViewCell (MyCell).

In storyboard, I can't change the location of the UIIMageView to fill my custom UICollectionViewCell. 
I have tried adjust the values in attribute / size inspector. But that does not work.

Can you please help me solve my issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're editing the properties of the cell, not the image view. Select the "Image View" item you see in the left column or double-click it on the canvas.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get it to work. editing which properties of the cell? My Collection View has items = 1. Cell size is w=373 h=174. My Cell View has 'Frame Rectangle' as View. It size is w=373 h=174 x=0 y=128. these values I can't change.